# CSS make div show on the right side

Tags: html, css

First of all, I'm totally new on CSS, so maybe this is pretty simple, but I have tried with no success, so I decided to ask here, since other answers didn't work for me (using float: right, etc.) :(

I'm using [this pen](https://codepen.io/8eni/pen/YWoRGm) to make a whatsapp chat. But I'd like that the bubble-alt was showing at the right of the browser, no matter the size of it.
I tried with the `float` attribute, like this:

```
.speech-wrapper .bubble {
  width: 240px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 8px 5px #000;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  float: left;
} 
.speech-wrapper .bubble.alt {
   margin: 0 0 0 60px;
   float: right;
}
```

But when I try it, it is a mess, and the bubbles are all around the screen. 
Also, I tried adding margin to the right, but it's like there was no margin. It comes to the left.

Is there any way to make the "normal" bubble show at the left of the screen and the "alt" bubble at the right?

Comment: You are required to show the complete markup that shows the problem here, not CodePen: [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margin for alt should be set to margin-left auto.
Here is a modified [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKJwzg)

```
.bubble{
  width: 240px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 8px 5px #000;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  &.alt{
    margin-left: auto; <--- here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this:

```
.speech-wrapper .bubble.alt {
    float: right;
}
.bubble {
  clear: both;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzVPNj

(The `clear: both;` makes sure all the bubbles are *below*  each other)